# In this object.assign line, why is there a repeat of state in the sources?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I understand that concat clones a new array of state.articles with action.payload so why is state needed as a first source. Is it because an object of state of array state.articles + action.payload is created?

```
import { ADD_ARTICLE } from "../constants/action-types";
const initialState = {
  articles: []
};
function rootReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  if (action.type === ADD_ARTICLE) {
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
      articles: state.articles.concat(action.payload)
    });
  }
  return state;
```

Comment: In this very case it's not needed, but it's just a general pattern for cases when you have more than one property and only mutate one of those.

Comment: It's keeping the store state immutable. Rather than directly changing properties on the state (mutating), it's creating an entirely new object

Comment: So it works too with Object.assign({}, { articles: state.articles.concat(action.payload)}); ?

Comment: @user56979: If your state 100% only has `articles` as single property, then yes it will works too

Answer (score 0):

```js
const initialState = {
  articles: []
};
function rootReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  if (action.type === ADD_ARTICLE) {
    return { ...state, articles: [...state.articles, action.payload] }
  }
  return state;
```

Your code can be shorten to above code. Do note that it's exactly equivalent to your code.

To answer your question, `articles` is only one of the properties, and `state` is an `object`(referring to `initialState` structure), and hence by having `Object.assign` will create an entire new set of `state`, which embracing [immutablity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object#:~:targetText=In%20object%2Doriented%20and%20functional,modified%20after%20it%20is%20created.).

Please do note that you are feel free to construct `state` into any data structure as you wished, as long as you're returning a new instance of the `state`, you're good to go. Usually we construct `state` as an `object` due to easier to scale horizontally